# Failed upgrade led all my packages to be from 18.04 even though I am running 16.04

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dependencies

```
# sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Fetched 88.7 kB in 0s (99.6 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
```

It's trying to update from bionic even though

```
$ lsb_release -a                                                                                                                                                                 
No LSB modules are available.                                                                                                                                                                 
Distributor ID: Ubuntu                                                                                                                                                                        
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS                                                                                                                                                            
Release:        16.04                                                                                                                                                                         
Codename:       xenial
```

When I do this it's Xenial. I can't even ssh to my server I need to use my emergency console tool from my VPS. If I try to install a new package it doesn't work. It says to upgrade my kernel but I am not able to do that because the VPS doesn't allow it.

```
$ sudo apt-get install openssh-server                                                                                                                                            
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                                                                                 
Building dependency tree                                                                                                                                                                      
Reading state information... Done                                                                                                                                                             
The following additional packages will be installed:                                                                                                                                          
  libc-bin libc6 libgssapi-krb5-2 libxext6 libxmuu1 openssh-client openssh-sftp-server python3-certifi python3-chardet python3-idna python3-pkg-resources python3-requests python3-six        
  python3-urllib3 ssh-import-id xauth                                                                                                                                                         
Suggested packages:                                                                                                                                                                           
  glibc-doc locales krb5-doc krb5-user keychain libpam-ssh monkeysphere ssh-askpass molly-guard rssh ufw python3-setuptools python3-cryptography python3-openssl python3-socks                
The following NEW packages will be installed:                                                                                                                                                 
  libgssapi-krb5-2 libxext6 libxmuu1 openssh-client openssh-server openssh-sftp-server python3-certifi python3-chardet python3-idna python3-pkg-resources python3-requests python3-six        
  python3-urllib3 ssh-import-id xauth                                                                                                                                                         
The following packages will be upgraded:                                                                                                                                                      
  libc-bin libc6                                                                                                                                                                              
2 upgraded, 15 newly installed, 0 to remove and 605 not upgraded.                                                                                                                             
Need to get 0 B/5166 kB of archives.                                                                                                                                                          
After this operation, 9286 kB of additional disk space will be used.                                                                                                                          
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1                                                                                                                          
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu11) ...                                                                                                                                         
Errors were encountered while processing:                                                                                                                                                     
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb                                                                                                                                        
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Did any upgrades run, or is just the sources and you can just revert them to xenial ? Check your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`.

Comment: I reverted them to the defaults and nothing changed.

Comment: How did you trying to upgrade your Ubuntu installation?